# CKEditor keyup event and capturing data from inline editors

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I'm trying to create a document with multiple inline CKEditor fields, and keyup is throwing me for a loop.  The "key" event works fine(but doesn't get the last character entered), however "keyups" aren't caught at all, unless I use the editor.document.on, which is what several other answers happily provided.

Unfortunately, since I have multiple(over 13) possible fields, the event seems to not return anything with it other than just the event itself.  No target information(I need the ID to pass to my save data function), nor the editor(to retrieve the content).

The objective is to save and validate the data being entered, as it's being entered.  I call them fields in my mind, but they're all divs(thus the inline editing).

Javascript:

```
$(function(){

CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;

$("div[contenteditable='true']" ).each(function( index ) {

    var content_id = $(this).attr('id');

    CKEDITOR.inline( content_id, {
        customConfig: '/majors/ckconfig.js'} );      
});


CKEDITOR.document.on('keyup', function(event){
      console.log(event.editor.getData()); // need to get the data, and the ID of the element.      
});
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you use [editor#change](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-change) event?

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.inline( content_id,
    { customConfig: '/majors/ckconfig.js' } ); 

editor.on( 'change', function() {
    console.log( editor.getData() );
} );
```

As for keydown, if you're still interested, you can add listener directly to the editable element:

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.inline( content_id,
    { customConfig: '/majors/ckconfig.js' } ); 

editor.on( 'contentDom', function() {
    var editable = editor.editable();
    editable.attachListener( editable, 'keyup', function() {
        console.log( editor.getData() );
    } );
} );
```

Read more about used methods in the [`editable#attachListener`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editable-method-attachListener) method documentation.

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  The on-change event was the solution.  I normally avoid that event for other html form stuff, because it usually seems to miss some actions I could consider "changes."  In this case, I guess CKEDITOR's own implementation does seem to catch everything I'm looking for.