# getText() method in CKEditor does not have the most recent text

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I am grabbing text that the user has written in the CKEditor text area on every keypress using:

```
var userText = CKEDITOR.instances.rawText;

userText.on( 'key', function() {
    var sentences = userText.document.getBody().getText();
     ...
}
```

However, I notice that the text that the `getText()` method returns is one keypress behind (i.e.: if I type the sentence "This is a sentence.", `getText()` will return "This is a sentence" (no period).

What is interesting is that if I log the result of the `getBody()` method to the console, I can see that it has the whole text including the most recent keypress. The `getData()` method, which returns the text, but with HTML tags also does not take into account the most recent keypress.

What is going on here? Is this a CKEditor issue or could it be JavaScript related?

EDIT:

I did some more Googling and found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24375780/ckeditor-keyup-event-and-capturing-data-from-inline-editors) mentioning the [editor#change](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-change) method. It seems to capture the most recent event, which is then returned in the `getText()` method. I will test this some more and add an answer to my question if this works.

Comment: Have you tried `on('keyup', function() {`

Comment: I just tried changing the event to "keyup", "keydown", and "keypress". None of them seem to fire. I am logging a few things to the console and they only show up when I use "key" as the event name.

Comment: OK, try `on('change', function() {` so there can be no doubt the input has been updated before the function fires.  What sort of element is `usertext`?

Comment: That's what I did (see edit). It appears to be working. usertext is an instance of CKEditor. I'll make another edit to add this